# couldnt install python-colorama

Tags: python, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install Jarvis ai from https://github.com/sukeesh/Jarvis *(I know it is not meant to be installed on windows 10. but I try it anyway)*

It said `no module named colorama`, so I typed `pip install python-colorama`. Then it said

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-colorama (from versions: )
No matching disribution found for python-colorama
```

I tried to install it using ubuntu, but different problem occurs: it said

```
Specify python version(2/3)(Default-3)3
Selected python version 3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 22, in <module>
    import distutils.spawn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
```

So its like asking 2 question in one. On windows it is

```
C:\Users\badarsyah\Jarvis>pip install python-colorama
Collecting python-colorama
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-colorama (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-colorama
```

But on ubuntu 18.04

```
aiki@LAPTOP-886AEJJG:~/Jarvis$ ./setup.sh
Specify python version(2/3)(Default-3)3
Selected python version 3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 22, in <module>
    import distutils.spawn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
```

I hope anyone can help, but please read the GitHub first so you can understand what im trying to do.

Comment: Indent code and improve English

Comment: This worked for me : https://askubuntu.com/a/1053059/339557

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by simply update pip with

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

then ran again the install command.